# Documenting and adding data sets using Roxygen2 producing Error: 'data' is not an exported object from 'namespace:package'

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have a package that uses a global variable to provide `errorCodes` for all the functions.  The data file, errorCodes.rda, is located in R\data.  According to the documentation for Roxygen2, I need to do the following to declare the variable:

```
    #' Error Codes
    #' 
    #' Error codes due values out of validity range, incorrect inputs,
    #'     and/or convergence issues
    #' 
    # #' @format 
    #'  
    #' @source errorCodes
    #' 
    "errorCodes"

globalVariables("errorCodes")
```

Unfortunately, this is giving me the error:

> ==> roxygen2::roxygenize('.', roclets = c('vignette'))
> ℹ Loading IAPWS95
> Error: 'errorCodes' is not an exported object from 'namespace:IAPWS95'
> Execution halted
>
> Exited with status 1.

I've tried the following and the error goes away:

```
    #' Error Codes
    #' 
    #' Error codes due values out of validity range, incorrect inputs,
    #'     and/or convergence issues
    #' 
    # #' @format 
    #'  
    #' @source errorCodes
    #' 
    NULL
    # "errorCodes"
    
    # globalVariables("errorCodes")
```

However, the package cannot find 'errorCodes` making the functions unusable.  I have added `LazyData:  TRUE` to my `DESCRIPTION` file.

The first used to work until recently.

Can anyone off me a clue as to how to fix this?

Comment: Does your `DESCRIPTION` file include `LazyData: true` ? It should if you want to load the data without using `data(errorCodes)`. See [R Packages](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#sec-data-data) by Hadley Wickham and Jenny Bryan for more.

Comment: Yes, my `DESCRIPTION` file contains `LazyData: true`.  I'll add that to the question.  Thanks!

Comment: This issue was resolved by moving the data from /R/Data to the top level, /Data, for the creation of the package.  This completely solved the issue

Comment: Great glad it was solved. That's where data should be. How did you end up with it in R/Data? I usually create datasets with `usethis::use_data()` which puts it in the right place.

Comment: This is where the dat was stored when I took over administration of the package.